# Synthesis gradient observer

Tags: calculus, control-theory, gradient-descent, adaptive-control

I ask the advice of specialists on control systems. We have the following system.

[image]

Where $u(t)$ and $y(t)$ time-varying input and output. The characteristic $y(t)=f(u(t))$ is assumed to be non-inertial.

Only input and output are available for measurement.

Let me make a reservation that the variant of estimating this derivative by the Euler method, i.e.

$g(t)=\frac{y_{n}(t)-y_{n-1}(t)}{u_{n}(t)-u_{n-1}(t)}$

is not suitable, since the system does not allow elements of delays (delay by 1 time step).

*Is it possible to construct an observer estimating the gradient* $g(t)=\frac{dy}{du}$?

Comment: You can collect a bunch of input/output data pairs and then use any method you like to learn the function f, i.e., linear regression, SVM, NN, etc. Then once you have f taking the gradient will give you g.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve, my questions can be quite amateurish. Please be understanding, I just started to study the theory of observers. Can you frame this as an answer?